# Proof that differential of differential form $=0$ i.e $d(df) = 0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function on an open space $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Proove that $d(df) = 0$.

So my proof is:

Let

$$f = \sum c_{i_1, \cdots i_k}(x_*)dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots dx_{i_k}$$

where $c_{i_1, \cdots i_k}$ are constants and $x_* = (x_1, \cdots x_n)$. We then get

$$df = \sum d[c_{i_1, \cdots i_k}(x_*)] \wedge dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots dx_{i_k}$$
$$\implies d(df) = \sum d\{ d[c_{i_1, \cdots i_k}(x_*)] \wedge dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots dx_{i_k}\} = 0.$$

How does that last line $=0$ though?

Comment: Is it because as soon as I do the differential of $\{ d[c_{i_1, \cdots i_k}(x_*) \wedge \cdots\}$ I end up wedging each term with itself eventually and so that just becomes $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be trying to prove it for $k$-forms. It also works and the proof is basically the same. What you say in the comment is correct. If $f$ is a smooth function then $df=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)dx^i$. So when you take $d$ again you get $d(df)=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}(x)dx^j\wedge dx^i.$ Now you only need to write this in terms of $\{dx^k\wedge dx^l:k<l\}$ which is the standard basis for $2$-forms.

Hint: Recall that $dx^i\wedge dx^i=0$ and $dx^i\wedge dx^j=-dx^j\wedge dx^i$.

Comment: Oh ok, so when I expand that sum, I'm going to get a whole load of $dx^i \wedge dx^i$ which will cancel, but then I get the rest to be in the form $(blah) (dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dx_2 \wedge dx_3 \cdots)$ which doesn't cancel?

Comment: In the expression of $d(df)$ above you have terms like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}dx^1\wedge dx^2$ and also like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}dx^2\wedge dx^1$. Try to think what happens when you put them together. In other words try to figure out what is A in $d(df)=Adx^1\wedge dx^2+$ "the rest".

Comment: Ohhh, sorry! I misread your other bit. I thought I just had to work them all out each time I had some $k < l$ and therefore couldn't do it the other way round. I get it now. Thanks :)