# Prove that $d(df)=0$ for any $0$-form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

As [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387924/proof-that-differential-of-differential-form-0-i-e-ddf-0) shown the exterior derivative of the exterior derivative of a $0$-form of class $C^r$ for $r\ge 2$ is $0$ but as you can show the function $f:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by the equation
$$
f(x,y):=\begin{cases}0\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\,(x,y)=(0,0)\\\frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^2+y^2},\,\,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
for any $x,y\in\Bbb R^2$ is of class $C^1$ and it is such that $f_{yx}(0,0)=-f_{xy}(0,0)=1$ so that $d(df)=(f_{xy}-f_{y,x})dx\wedge dy\neq0$ but unfortunately when my text (and **others too**) define the exterior derivative $d$ did not say that $d(df)=0$ only if $f\in C^r$ for $r\ge 2$ but when it prove this property it use the Schwartz theorem so that I am forced to say that this result holds only in the case where $r\ge 2$ because it could be to exist a scalar function $f$ of class $C^1$ whose derivative is differentiable and such that some mixed partial derivatives are note equal in any point. So I ask how the facts actually stand. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Can't you directly compute d(df)?

Comment: @Divide1918 The direct computation is in the link I posted in the question.

Comment: No I meant for your particular function f (assume that it's $C^1$ since otherwise you already know $d(df)=0$ holds).

Comment: @Divide1918 Why $d(df)=0$ if $$[d(df)](0)=[(f_{xy}-f_{yx})dx\wedge dy](0)=(f_{xy}-f_{yx})(0)[dx\wedge dy](0)=2[dx\wedge dy](0)=\\2dx(0)\wedge dy(0)\neq 0$$ since $dx(0)$ and $dy(0)$ are the elements of the dual basis? Is incorect what I said?

Comment: @Divide1918 Could you show to me why $d(d f)=0$, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Can you find df for your f?

Comment: @Divide1918 Surely $df=f_xdx+f_ydy$ as it is well known.

Comment: @Divide1918 Anyway I know that $d(df)=\sum_{i<j}^n(D_iD_j f-D_j D_if)dx_i\wedge dx_j$ and this is alway true for any $C^1$ function so that in particular $d(df)=(f_{xy}-f_{yx})dx\wedge dy$ for any scalar function $f$ defined in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Divide1918 So could you show to me why $d(df)=0$ in the above particular case?

Comment: How do you define $df$ is $f$ is not differentiable? Does $d^2f$ have any sense for a function that is not twice differentiable?

Comment: Yes, you will need symmetry of partial derivatives for ddf to be 0 and this need not always hold. Usually, whenever one uses forms everything in sight is smooth, however, so this is a non-issue.

Comment: @Dlier_ My text define $df$ simply through the equation $$[df(x)](x;\vec v):=Df(x)\cdot v$$ for any $x,v\in\Bbb R^n$ and doing this it not require that $f$ must be differentiable.

Comment: @DIdier_ Anyway the function $f$ I above defined is of class $C^1$ and so it is differentiable too. This is incorrect?

Comment: Look closely to your book. My point is that $Df$ is defined only for differentiable function. Thus $DDf$ is defined for functions that are twice differentiable. If a function $f$ is only $C^1$, $Df$ exists but $DDf$ does not.

Comment: @Dldier Okay, so substantially $d(d f)$ is defined only for functions of class $C^r$ with $r\ge 2$, right?

Comment: For twice differentiable functions, and then, $DDf = 0$ is just, in coordinates, the Schwarz lemma

Comment: @Dldier_ Surely, I proved it. The problem was that I did not understand that the exterior derivative is substatially defined only for differentiable functions, that's all. Anyway if we like it we can define the exterior derivative even for not differentiable functions, right? Probably it is very stranger but it is not incorrect with respect the usual definition of exterior derivative, right?

Comment: How would you define it? The definition involves some derivative of the function itself, so the function must of course be differentiable to define its differential. Hence the name "differential"

Comment: So first I define the exterior derivative of a $0$-form thorugh the equation $$[df(x)](x;\vec v):=Df(x)\cdot \vec v$$ for any $x,v\in\Bbb R^n$ and so if $\omega$ is a $k$-form for $k>0$ I define $d\omega$ through the equation $$d\omega:=\sum_{i_1<...<i_k}df_{i_1,...,i_k}\wedge dx^{i_1,...,i_k}$$ where $f_{i_1,..,.i_k}$ is a $0$-form for each increasing $k$-uple of indices $i_1,...,i_k$ such that $$\omega=\sum_{i_1<...<i_k}f_{i_1,...,i_k}dx^{i_1,...,i_k}$$ and as you can see this definition required only that there the coefficents of a form must be derivable. So what can you say about?

Comment: I would say that by definiton, a differential form is said to be differentiable if (and only if) its coefficients in a chart (hence, in any chart) are differentiable. So you did not invent anything else that what is already defined.

Comment: Yes, surely! So this what implies?

Comment: I don't get your point, and I will stop discussing about this because it seems to go nowhere. I would conclude that it seems pointless to define a differential of a non-differentiable function.

Comment: @Dldier_ Okay, do not worry. Thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @Dldier_ In any case I was thinking that it could exist a scalar function $f$ of class $C^1$ whose derivative is continuous and differentiable and in this case the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387924/proof-that-differential-of-differential-form-0-i-e-ddf-0) I posted in the question is not valid. So how prove that $d(df)=0$ supposing that it is of class $C^1$ and that it is derivative is differetiable? Could you answer to this? Excuse me for the bother.

Comment: When defining $d$, one usually assume that $f$ is smooth. If not, one usually assume that $d, d^2....$ are defined in the distribution sense (which is well-defined even for measurable functions), and we  have $d^2 f = 0$ by definition.

Comment: @ArcticChar Okay, but unfortunately I have not studied distributions: so I have to conlude that my text define the exterior derivative letting that the differential exterior operator $d$ is a linear transformation from $\Omega^k(V)$ to $\Omega^{k+1}(V)$ such that $d(d\omega))=0$ for any $k$-form $\omega$ of calss $C^r$ with $r\ge 2$? There is not another "simple" way to prove what I asked?

Comment: I don't know which text you are using, so I can't tell what to conclude.

Comment: @ArcticChar My text is *Analysis on Manifold* by James Munkres and he assumes that the forms are substantially or of class $C^r$ for $r\ge1$ either of class $C^\infty$ as he prefers.

Comment: How does he define $d$ of a $k$-form?

Comment: @ArcticChar  So first he defines the exterior derivative of a $0$-form thorugh the equation
$$[df(x)](x;\vec v ):=Df(x)\cdot\vec v$$ 
for any $x,v∈\Bbb R^n$ and so if $ω$ is a k-form for $k>0$ he defines $dω$ through the equation
$$dω:=∑_{i_1<...<i_k}df_{i_1,...,i_k}∧dx^{i_1,...,i_k}$$
where $f_{i_1,..,.i_k}$ is a $0$-form for each increasing k-uple of indices $i_1,...,i_k$ such that
$$ω=∑_{i_1<...<i_k}f_{i_1,...,i_k}dx^{i_1,...,i_k}$$
and he e hypothesize  that the coefficients of a form are of class $C^r$ for $r\ge 1$. So what can you say now?

Comment: Well, isn't you answered your own question then? To define $d(df)$ you need that $df$ has $C^1$ coefficients.

Comment: @ArcticChar Not properly: indeed if $f$ is  a scalar function of class $C^1$ whose derivative is differentiable and such that some mixed partial derivatives are not equal in some points then it seem to me that it could be $d(df)\neq  0$ by the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387924/proof-that-differential-of-differential-form-0-i-e-ddf-0) I posted. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Can you list me an example of $f$ that is $C^1$ but not $C^2$, but all the derivatives are $C^1$?

Comment: There have been way too many comments already and I refuse to read half of them. Bottom line is this: Almost every textbook I know that treats differential forms assumes all forms in question are $C^\infty$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I posted in the question but I do not know if its derivative is differentiable.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, I understand. Anyway to summarize the comment I say to you that the answer to the question is if there exist a scalar function of class $C^1$ whose derivative is differentiable ans such that some mixed partial derivatives are not equal in some points: so do you know that there exist a such function? That's all.

Comment: Wait, can you state your definition of $C^1$ function?

Comment: No. If the derivative is differentiable as a map $U\to L(\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R)$, then its derivative is symmetric. This is proved, for example, in Dieudonné's analysis book.

Comment: @ArcticChar A function if of class $C^1$ if can be derived and if its derivative is continuous.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I saw. Thanks to much for the answer!!!